# Pandas Dataframe calculate Time difference for each group and Time difference between two different groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe like that:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Time': ['01.07.2019, 06:21:33', '01.07.2019, 06:32:01', '01.07.2019, 06:57:33', '01.07.2019, 07:24:33','01.07.2019, 08:26:25', '01.07.2019, 09:12:44']
     ,'Action': ['Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed']
     ,'Name': ['Bayer', 'Bayer', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'Geco' , 'Geco'],
               'Group': ['1', '1', '2','2','3','3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

output:

    Time                    Action  Name    Group
0   01.07.2019, 06:21:33    Opened  Bayer   1
1   01.07.2019, 06:32:01    Closed  Bayer   1
2   01.07.2019, 06:57:33    Opened  ITM     2
3   01.07.2019, 07:24:33    Closed  ITM     2
4   01.07.2019, 08:26:25    Opened  Geco    3
5   01.07.2019, 09:12:44    Closed  Geco    3
```

so now i'm trying to calculate the Time difference for each group and the Time difference between these groups in minutes. So For example the Time difference in the Group Bayer should be 10 minutes and 28 seconds and the Time difference between Bayer and ITM should be 25 minutes and 32 seconds. After that the Time difference between the same group should be displayed in a column at the same line where the group begins and the Time difference between two different groups should be displayed in another column at the same line where the group ends.

so the wished Output would be:

```
    Time                    Action  Name    Group Time Difference(names) Time Difference(groups)
0   01.07.2019, 06:21:33    Opened  Bayer   1          10:28
1   01.07.2019, 06:32:01    Closed  Bayer   1                                   25:32
2   01.07.2019, 06:57:33    Opened  ITM     2          27:00         
3   01.07.2019, 07:24:33    Closed  ITM     2                                   1:01:52
4   01.07.2019, 08:26:25    Opened  Geco    3          46:19
5   01.07.2019, 09:12:44    Closed  Geco    3
```

how could i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by making datetime from string, then some groupbys and diffs:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df["d1"] = df.groupby("Name")["Time"].diff().shift(-1).fillna("")
df["d2"] = (
    df.groupby((df["Action"] == "Closed").cumsum())["Time"]
    .diff()
    .shift(-1)
    .fillna("")
)
```

produces

```
|    | Time                | Action   | Name   |   Group | d1              | d2              |
|---:|:--------------------|:---------|:-------|--------:|:----------------|:----------------|
|  0 | 2019-01-07 06:21:33 | Opened   | Bayer  |       1 | 0 days 00:10:28 |                 |
|  1 | 2019-01-07 06:32:01 | Closed   | Bayer  |       1 |                 | 0 days 00:25:32 |
|  2 | 2019-01-07 06:57:33 | Opened   | ITM    |       2 | 0 days 00:46:19 |                 |
|  3 | 2019-01-07 07:24:33 | Closed   | ITM    |       2 |                 | 0 days 01:01:52 |
|  4 | 2019-01-07 08:26:25 | Opened   | Geco   |       3 | 0 days 00:27:00 |                 |
|  5 | 2019-01-07 09:12:44 | Closed   | Geco   |       3 |                 |                 |
```

to explain a bit the `d2` calc, this `(df['Action'] == 'Closed').cumsum()` increments by 1 for each new `'Closed'` row. Here I print it alongside `Action` for clarity, using this

```
df['d2_cond'] = (df['Action'] == 'Closed').cumsum()
df[['Action', 'd2_cond']]
```

prints

```
Action  d2_cond
0   Opened  0
1   Closed  1
2   Opened  1
3   Closed  2
4   Opened  2
5   Closed  3
```

so we can `groupby` on this list to put together each `Closed` with the corresponding next `Opened`

Comment: great answer. can you elaborate creation of d2, a little bit of explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @piterbarg so thats working fine!! great! Another question: If the Time in the next line is for example the next day, is it possible to calculate from the beginning? so not that there is like 1 day and 20 minutes

Comment: @Arthi Glad it helped. I am not sure I understand your follow up question though. from the beginning of what?

Comment: @piterbarg so for example: if we have in the dataframe the same name but the date is different: ( 01.07.2019 14:55:57, Opened, ITM, 1), (02.07.2019 06:55:12, Closed, ITM) it would calculate the whole day so how could i do that if the next day comes in the next line it should stop at 14:55:57 and calculate from 0 at the next day?

Comment: you can figure out the offset for each timestamp from the midnight of that day by something like `df['d3'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda d: d - d.floor('d'))`.

Comment: @piterbarg im a little bit confused so if im using this, it shows me the time from midnight right? So how can i add that to my calculation if the day ends it should stop calculating and it is the next day to calculate from the beginning at this point?